# What is the highest achievable score in Catan

Tags: catan, scoring

The game ends as soon as you get 10 or more points, so even if you can build multiple things, the one that gets you to 10 is it.

I'm fairly certain that the highest score possible in Catan is 12 points. Assuming you are at 9 points, and are in second place for longest road, if you were able to build a settlement that broke up longest road that would give you three points at once.

Is there a way to end with a higher score?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The game ends when you reach 10 points on your turn, so if you are playing with 5 or 6 players you could easily get high then 10 on the special build phases so it would be closer to the maximum number of points possible with the amount of building you have.

5 point for settlements

8 points for cities

4 for longest road and largest army

5 in hidden victory points
So in theory you could get to 22 points if you are extremely lucky.

taken from the rule book on ending the game:
"If you have—or reach—10 victory points on your turn, the game ends immediately and you win! You can only win during your turn. If somehow you find you have 10 victory points during another player’s turn, you must wait until your next turn to claim victory"

Comment: Did some calculation and assuming you had 3 cities, 1 settlement, largest army and you could take longest road by building a settlement.  You would need 36 cards to pull this off and to only pull victory points from development cards.

Comment: What is the date on your rule book? I don't remember that requirement from older copies.

Comment: If you have for example 3 cities, that makes 6 points in the eyes of the other players. You could have also 3 hidden points and 2 army cards, and in the end of your turn get another army card (which would give you the extra 1 point - 2 indeed - needed) you still have to wait one turn to unfold it. In the meantime, someone could break longest road and inmediately make yours the longest. So, in the start of your next turn, you unfold the army and you get a total of 13 points (6 for cities, 3 for hidden points, 2 for biggest army and 2 for longest road)

Comment: @DIe rules state you can't play a card you buy until the next turn unless this would win you the game....

Comment: @fireshark519 isn't that only with "victory point cards"? If not, I've been "a whole life" playing mistakenly my favourite game

Comment: If you look at the rules for victory point cards it is the exception to the rule.
Text from the rule book: 
"You must keep Victory Point Cards hidden. You may only
reveal them during your turn and when you are sure that you
have 10 victory points—that is, to win the game. Of course,
you can reveal them after the end of the game when someone
else wins. You may play any number of Victory Point Cards
during your turn, even during the turn you purchase them."
Link to rule book i have used: https://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Although the maximum is 22 points, this is not possible in a real game, because the game stops as soon as one player has 10 or more points. So we need to find the maxium number of points that can be met in a single action.

- Building a road, can give you at most 2 points, if you get the longest road.
- With a development card, can give you at most 2 points:

  - You can play a knight, and getting the largest army (2 points)
  - You can play two roads and get the longest road (2 points)
  - You can buy a victory point (only 1 point).
- While building a settlement or city, you can get 1 point. But there is a case where you can get 3 points:

  - You build a settlement (1 point)
  - The settlement disrupts the longest road of an other player
  - You now have the longest road (2 additional points).

So if you have 9 points, you build a settlement that disrupts the longest road and you have the next longest road, you get 3 points for a total of 12 points.

With expansions, you can get more points, but this is for the basic game.